# Cannot read a binary file with red from http

Tags: red

```
write %test.zip read/binary https://sourceforge.net/projects/agena/files/latest/download?source=directory?SetFreedomCookie
```

doesn't download the file because there is a redirect. Is there a way to tell to follow redirect before reading ?

Comment: Red's READ does follow redirects, but doesn't appear to do so correctly in this instance. You could use CURL via CALL using the `-L` flag to follow the redirect.

Comment: @rgchris I tried to do so but something must be missing in my syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041154/call-curl-from-rebol-or-red-doesnt-work