# call curl from rebol or red doesn't work

Tags: curl, rebol, red

On dos cmd this works:

```
curl.exe -L https://dl.uxnr.de/build/curl/curl_winssl_msys2_mingw64_stc/curl-7.53.1/curl-7.53.1.zip > curl.zip
```

On red or rebol, following suggestion [Cannot read a binary file with red from http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008894/cannot-read-a-binary-file-with-red-from-http), I tried code below but it doesn't work why ?

```
call {curl.exe -L https://dl.uxnr.de/build/curl/curl_winssl_msys2_mingw64_stc/curl-7.53.1/curl-7.53.1.zip > curl.zip}
```

I also tried call/wait, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebol2:

```
call/output {curl.exe -L https://www.example.com} data: make string! estimated-big-enough-number
```

Rebol3 (Ren/C branch):

```
call/shell/output {curl -L https://www.example.com} data: make binary! 0

;; or

call/output [%/path/to/curl "-L" "https://www.example.com"] data: make binary! 0

;;or a poor mans solution as in e.g.

 call {curl -L -k https://dl.uxnr.de/build/curl/curl_winssl_msys2_mingw64_stc/curl-7.53.1/curl-7.53.1.zip  > this-I-want } data: read %this-I-want
```

Red:

```
call/output {curl -L -k https://dl.uxnr.de/build/curl/curl_winssl_msys2_mingw64_stc/curl-7.53.1/curl-7.53.1.zip} data: make binary! 100'000
```

Comment: string ? why on earth since it's binary file :)

Comment: @user310291 Can also say **`data: make binary! ...`**

Comment: I modified the answer so that it works for Red and Rebol2

Comment: My version of R3 is 2.101.0.3.1 and 'call has no refinements for /shell or /output. It only supports /wait. Any tips on how to get capture the data that comes back from cURL?

Comment: You can try a redirect and then read it as in **call "ls -l > this-I-want" data: read %this-I-want**